# Link to question missing during "Improve Edit"

Tags: feature-request, edits, comments, suggested-edits

When going through Suggested Edits, sometimes you would like

1. first to improve the edit

and, after editing

2. to provide a comment to the question.

---

Just improving the edit is easy, because you just click "Improve Edit" button, edit and save.

Also just providing a comment is easy, because you can just click the title of the question containing link in Suggested Edits and provide the comment to the question in a separate browser tab.

---

But what happens if you already clicked "Improve Edit" edited the question?

Then you have two options which both are *a bit problematic*:

- "Save Edit" ... this button saves the edits and *jumps to the next question in suggested edits*

  - Leaving a comment to the question is not easy, because you just lost the question from your sight and have to find it.
- "Cancel" ... this button *loses your edits* but goes back to the same position in suggested edits

  - You can again click the question, but leaving comment to the question is unpleasant, because you had first to reject your edits.

---

It would be nice to **have a link to the edited question in hand also in "Improve Edit" window**, so that if you happened to edit the question, you would not need to reject your edits in order go back to "Suggested Edits" and find a link to the question from there.

Therefore, I suggest to

- add button/link with text "Link to question" (or any other text like "Link", "Link to unedited version", etc.) into the status bar, for example, left to "Improving..."
  [image]

---

Similar problem is not present, if you click "Edit" when looking a question or an answer in usual window, because there editing keeps also the commenting visible. However, I am not suggesting to provide full functionality of commenting in "Improve Edit" mode, just a link to the full page where you can review all questions and answers.

Comment: This has been a feature request since 2012: [Can we have a link back to the original question when improving an edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142284/289905). This is not specific to Stack Overflow, hence it was posted on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: You can also click Save Edit, then click the back button on your browser. It will show the history of the review of the question, and you can click the title to open the question (middle-click or Ctrl+left-click or right-click and choose open in new tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clicking Save Edit, the browser is redirected to the next question in the queue. You can click the back button of the browser to navigate back to the question you just edited. The box will show your improvement and a Community approval of the edit. You can use the title of the question as a link, using whatever browser/OS-specific key combination you need to to open it in a new tab.

[image: Picture of edit page with gratuitous free hand circle around title]